# Restore Office Environment to Default after development

Tags: vsto

After I develop my add-in for Microsoft Office ( and in the process messed up all my menu bars and tool bars) using Visual Studio For Office, is there anyway to restore the MS Office to default?

For the record, Clean Solution alone is ***not*** enough!

Comment: Just reset toolbar. pretty easy, question should be on superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try repair? Always have an updated image of the drive, it comes in handy.

Comment: Thanks, but repair? May I know what to repair? Are you referring to repairing the office application itself ( such as MS Word)?

Comment: I believe he means perform a repair install.

Comment: Oh, a repair install is definitely not feasible.

Comment: Hi, right click on the menu bar or toolbar and use the "Reset Button"...hope that helps